# Looping javascript multiselect form elements

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, post

I am trying to loop the values of a multiselect checkboxes so that I can split the array and post them as one string.  In PHP you can just say:

```
implode(",", $_POST['usage'])
```

to get a comma separated string.  How would I get the same in javascript or using jquery for the source below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="usage[]" id="usage-ContentManagement" value="Content Management">
<input type="checkbox" name="usage[]" id="usage-Personal" value="Personal">
<input type="checkbox" name="usage[]" id="usage-Business" value="Business">
<input type="checkbox" name="usage[]" id="usage-SmallBusiness" value="Small Business">
```

I have tried `$('[name="usage[]"]').val()` but it will always give "Content Management" even if the checkbox is not selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the checkboxes and store their values in an array. Then "implode" this array.

```
var arr = [];
$('[name="usage[]"]:checked').each(function(){
    arr.push(this.value);
});
alert(arr.join(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`$.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

```
var values = $('[name="usage[]"]').serializeArray().map(function(kvp) {
    // kvp has the form {name:..., value:...}
    return kvp.value;
}).join(',');
```

The advantage is that you can use this for any form element: check boxes, radio boxes, selects, text inputs,... `$.serializeArray` makes sure that the appropriate values are retrieved.

Comment: Great idea as well, but more than I needed